# Regex to replace punctuation

Tags: php, regex

I've been trying for a few hours to get this to work to the effect I need but nothing works quite like it should. I'm building a discussion board type thing and have made a way to tag other users by putting `@username` in the post text.

Currently I have this code to strip anything that wouldn't be part of the username once the tags have already been pulled out of the entire text:

```
$name= preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/",'',$name);
```

This works well because it correct captures names that are for example `(@username)`, `@username:`, `@username, some text` etc. (so to remove the `,`, `:`, and `)`).

HOWEVER, this does not work when the user has non-ascii characters in their username. For example if it's `@üsername`, the result of that line above gives `sername` which is not useful.

IS there a way using preg_replace to still strip these additional punctuation, but retain any non-ascii letters?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect punctuation characters, you can use unicode property `\p{P}` instead:

```
$name = preg_replace('/[\p{P} ]+/', '', $name);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qX2vH6/2)

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/[[:punct:]]+/', '', '—');`— you might try it yourself by copy-pasting the string I provided. It’s _mdash_, which is apparently is not handled by `[[:punct:]]`.

Comment: THANKS anubhava! That was so much easier than I thought it would be :)

Comment: @hashi Even despite the fact this answer is **wrong** and the regexp provided does not filter _all_ punctuation (see my previous comment)? OK, whether it’s OK for you, it’s OK for me.

Comment: @anubhava My answer is already working while yours still leaves in the string garbage like non-breakable spaces, unicode dashes and much more. I brand this answer wrong just because it **is** wrong.

Comment: @mudasobwa:If your answer was correct from start what made you to modify it multiple times?

Comment: @anubhava That’s kinda insane. I never told about correctness from the start. I am talking that here, on SO, you should not leave upvoted wrong answers: http://regex101.com/r/xW8iH8/1 — look how your expression handles space. http://regex101.com/r/lT1cC9/1 — and colons.

Comment: That can be easily fixed by using `[[:punct:] :]+` but again it depends what punctuation characters OP wants to handle.

Comment: @anubhava: being defensive isn't really helpful. Your answer is wrong in at least two ways: first, blacklisting is never reliable, second, no unicode support. Please fix it.

Comment: @anubhava: "whitelist" = match what you want to keep (reliable), "blacklist" = match what you want to remove (unreliable, since there's always a chance you forget something).

Comment: Yes but I thought blacklist is negation based regex that starts with `[^...]`. IMO definition of a punctuation character class has some variations. Usually space is not considered part of punctuation for example.

Comment: Guys, I used the original answer (before it was edited) and it serves it's intended purpose after testing on all cases where my previous code wasn't working.

Comment: @hashi: If it worked for you, consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You enter the area of [Unicode Regexps](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

```
$name= preg_replace('/[^\p{Letter}\p{Number}_]/u', '', $name);
```

or the other way round. The link I provided contains more examples.

Comment: This answer looks better to me, because whitelisting is a preferred way (match what you want to keep, not what you want to remove).